# Golang url.Parse always return Invalid Control Character URL

Tags: go, scrape

I'm trying to scrape some site using proxy that i get from free-proxy-list.net and apply it in my local http request using Golang, but when i parse the proxy using url.Parse() always return Invalid Control Character URL

```
func getProxy() *url.URL {
    proxyUrl := "https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http&country=US"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", proxyUrl, nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error proxy ", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error response body", err)
    }
    details := string(body)
    temp := strings.Split(details, "\n")
    fmt.Println("http://" + temp[rand.Intn(30)])
    checkProxy, err := url.Parse("http://" + temp[rand.Intn(10)])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Bad proxy URL", err)
    }

    return checkProxy
}
```

Comment: This means the URL is invalid. It is that simple.

Comment: @Volker, but when i try it manually example "http://104.129.11.35:3128" it's work

but when i try to get the value from strings.split, it's always return Invalid Control Character URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> proxyUrl := "https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http&country=US"
> ```

The content of this URL are lines in the format `ip:port\r\n´, i.e. the line delimiter is`\r\n`, (DOS/Windows style).

> ```
> temp := strings.Split(details, "\n")
> ```

This splits the content by `\n`, i.e. the UNIX style line delimiter. This leaves the `\r` from the DOS line delimiter in the string, resulting in `ip:port\r`.

> ...  always return Invalid Control Character URL

It is the remaining `\r` in the line it is complaining about.

Answer (score 3):

There are trailing spaces and carriage returns in the proxy list.
Try

```
fmt.Println("http://" + strings.TrimSpace(temp[rand.Intn(30)]))
checkProxy, err := url.Parse("http://" + strings.TrimSpace(temp[rand.Intn(10)]))
```

This works.